# Set environment variables in Quarkus to deploy in Openshift

Tags: environment-variables, openshift, quarkus

I want to deploy my quarkus application in Openshift. I am trying to make the connection to the database with some environment variables whose value will be indicated in a configmap file and in a secrets file.

I have a my-configmap.yaml like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config-map
data:
  db-url: jdbc:postgresql://postgresql/databasename
```

I also have a my-secret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  db-username: username
  db-password: password
```

My application.properties file:

```
quarkus.openshift.app-config-map=my-config-map
quarkus.openshift.app-secret=my-secret
quarkus.openshift.env.configmaps=my-config-map
quarkus.openshift.env.secrets=my-secret
quarkus.openshift.env.mapping.DB_URL.from-configmap=my-config-map
quarkus.openshift.env.mapping.DB_URL.with-key=db-url
quarkus.openshift.env.mapping.DB_USERNAME.from-secret=my-secret
quarkus.openshift.env.mapping.DB_USERNAME.with-key=db-username
quarkus.openshift.env.mapping.DB_PASSWORD.from-secret=my-secret
quarkus.openshift.env.mapping.DB_PASSWORD.with-key=db-password

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
quarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=${DB_URL}
```

I have tried in several ways (`quarkus.kubernetes.env...` instead of `quarkus.openshift.env`) but I can't get it to work. I have also tried to create a deployment config from openshift in which I indicate the environment variables but nothing.

What am I doing wrong or how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I could understand that you have 2 components (1 is your application pod and 2nd is your postgres DB running in your openshift custer) & you are trying to connect to postgres db from your application.

Here secret & Configmap looks fine

By default, When you create your Postgres DB in cluster (deployment config) ... Service is created and 5432 port is exposed. you should configure your app to point postgres service (host) & can be named as DB HOST instead or DB URL

So DB host details along with your DB username, Password, Host (postgres svc), DB name should be set in your application pod. When application pod start it establish connection with your postgres db

Hope this helps...

Comment: I have tried uploading the application with the connection data configured directly and it works fine for me. The problem comes when I want to get that information from some environment variables whose value is given in a cofigmap or in a secret.

Comment: you have to add "env"under .spec section of your pod/deployment . ref link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/